# Output nil:NilClass when raising an exception

Tags: ruby

When you call a method that does not exist on an object a NoMethodError will be raised i.e.

```
Object.new.foo
```

will output:

> NoMethodError: undefined method `foo' for #

while

```
nil.foo
```

will output:

> NoMethodError: undefined method `foo' for nil:NilClass

I want to copy this behaviour when raising an exception of my own, i.e.

```
foo = Object.new
raise StandardError, "#{foo} triggered an error"
```

which will output:

> StandardError: #`<Object:0xbf37748>` triggered an error

which is exatly what I want.

Unfortunately

```
foo = nil
raise StandardError, "#{foo} triggered an error"
```

will output

> StandardError:  triggered an error

which is probably because `nil.to_s` is `""`. How do I get `nil:NillClass` as output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
raise StandardError, "#{foo.inspect}:#{foo.class} triggered an error"
```

Edit. You seem to want `nil` to behave differently. So prepare a different method just for using in your `raise` statement.

```
class Object; def my_inspect; inspect end end
class NilClass; def my_inspect; "#{inspect}:#{self.class}" end end

raise StandardError, "#{foo.my_inspect} triggered an error"
```

Comment: This will make the output to verbose when the instance is not a NilClass.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I see how that could work. I wonder though how it is handled in ruby itself when for example a `NoMethodError` is triggered. The behaviour already exists in ruby, I just want to copy it. I tried searching trough the ruby source code, but couldn't find what I was looking for.

Comment: I think I didn't explain myself clearly enough. Your answer will work, but I want the same behaviour for each of those classes, exactly like the `NoMethodError` generates. So also for true (true:TrueClass) etc.

Comment: Then define the special version not within `NilClass` but within some module, and include that module into the relevant classes.

Comment: But wouldn't it be redundant to create such behaviour, when it already exists in ruby. Isn't there a way to copy the existing behaviour.

Comment: I think it should be somewhere in the C code, probably not accessible directly from Ruby.

Comment: In that case your answer is an acceptable solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can call `foo.class`. Something like:

```
raise StandardError, "#{foo.class} triggered an error"
```

This will only output NilClass but this should be informative enough.

Comment: Yes you can do that, but since it is already done in ruby error handling, it only seems right to mimic that behaviour. Also if I call it like that it would change the output of for example Object.new to just Object instead of #<Object:0xbf37748>, which gives the impression that it mentions a class instead of an instance, which is something I'm trying to avoid.